# Read-only projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Would there be any reason that VS would prohibit you to "Add existing file" to lets say a folder inside an assembly?

Is it protected somehow?  If so how and where is this done and how can I see if this is the case?

There are some missing .cs class files in one of these folders that should be included in this project and I try adding them back in and get nothing, nothing happens...it doesn't show them added in VS.

Comment: Any form of version control implemented?

Comment: Another strange thing is in solution explorer, if I choose at the top to show hidden files, I should be seeing those .cs files anyway and I don't.  But I know they are there physically in that folder on my drive!

Comment: This was downloaded as read-only from Subversion.  But I thought that meant I just couldn't check files back into SVN.  Maybe it also prevents you from editing anything locally for that solution.

Comment: Try removing source control - If it's attached to source control, it will attempt to check out the solution/lock it/mark it as being edited depending on the project setup. This step would fail if it's read-only. See File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control...

Answer (score 2):

Is the project file marked "read only" if you check its properties? Double-check the project file just in case.

Also, try reloading the project. Or click the button at the top of the Solution Explorer that shows all files on disk and try including files through right-clicking them and selecting "Add to project".

And if all else fails, manually edit the csproj file. :)

Comment: No, the project properties has no read only settings.  I checked its source.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the obvious that adding files/modifying the project is disabled while the project is running, there shouldn't be any reason not to be able to - Is the option greyed out/do you get an error?

Comment: It's not running.  And when I right-click that folder and perform an "Add Existing File", I go browse to that file and chose it.  The dialog closes and I see nothing happen.  That folder in Solution Explorer still has the same contents and nothing additional was added.

Comment: Do you have permissions to modify the location where the project lives? Is VS running as you or another user? Is there anything unusual in your setup and does this happen only with one specific project or any project you open?

Answer (score 0):

The add operation could be failing for any of the following reasons:

- Source control is enabled on the project, and you have not checked out the project file.
- You are currently debugging something.
- A Visual Studio extension is attempting to "hook" the add command, and throwing an exception while handling the command which causes the project system to abort the operation.

Try selecting the affected project in Solution Explorer, and then clicking the Show All Files button at the top of Solution Explorer. You should see the source files appear in the appropriate folder, which you can then right click and select Include In Project.